# Unwanted thunk double-dispatch on useEffect with React 18 StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I'm trying to dispatch a thunk on a first render of the page and on a button click. Here's a sample code of it:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false);
  const count = useSelector(countSelector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const appendCounter = useCallback(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      setLoading(true);
      setFinished(false);

      dispatch(thunk()).finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        setFinished(true);
      });
    }
  }, [loading, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && !finished) {
      appendCounter();
    }
  }, [appendCounter, loading, finished]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!loading && finished ? (
        <>
          <h2>{count}</h2>
          <button onClick={appendCounter}>Append</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <h2>loading</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I'm using React 18 with StrictMode. On React 17 everything works fine, but on 18 I'm getting two dispatched thunks on the page render. I think that's due to [StrictMode changes in React 18](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state). How can I fix the code to prevent double-dispatching? The code is also available on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/double-dispatch-demo-1kdgmi).

Comment: Any solutions? Having the same issue. I think to solve this need to use refs.

Comment: @Evgeniy I partially solved it by using the [Canceling Before Execution feature in the Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-before-execution). Refs will also work, although it's more of a temporary solution, in my opinion. Both techniques affect the production runtime, that's sad.

Comment: yeah. I solved it too, by using useRef hook to store state trough twice-renders.